# Get Screen-Coordinates of a QuickControl

Tags: qt, qml, coordinates, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols

I have to set x,y coordinates of a `QWindow`. This `QWindow` has to get the screen coordinates of a `QuickControl` in my `MainWindow` + `myValue`.

How do I get the global Screen-Coordinates for a `QuickControl` in QML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @BaCaRoZzo mentioned, use the `mapToItem()`/`mapFromItem()` functions:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Button {
        id: button
        text: "Button"
        x: 100
        y: 100

        readonly property point windowPos: button.mapToItem(null, 0, 0)
        readonly property point globalPos: Qt.point(windowPos.x + window.x, windowPos.y + window.y)
    }

    Column {
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom

        Text {
            text: "Button position relative to window: x=" + button.windowPos.x + " y=" + button.windowPos.y
        }

        Text {
            text: "Button position relative to screen: x=" + button.globalPos.x + " y=" + button.globalPos.y
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#mapToItem-method-2) for `mapToItem()`:

> Maps the point (x, y) or rect (x, y, width, height), which is in this item's coordinate system, to item's coordinate system, and returns a point or rect matching the mapped coordinate.
>
> If item is a null value, this maps the point or rect to the coordinate system of the root QML view.

That gives us `windowPos`. To get the position of the control relative to the screen itself, we just add the `x` and `y` position of the window.

---

After a chat with OP, it's clear that he wants to do this in C++. The same principles apply, and in C++ we have more convenient access to the window:

```
class Control : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    Control() {}
    ~Control() {}

public slots:
    void printGlobalPos() {
        qDebug() << mapToItem(Q_NULLPTR, QPointF(0, 0)) + window()->position();
    }
};
```

Register the type:

```
qmlRegisterType<Control>("Types", 1, 0, "Control");
```

Use it in QML:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0

import Types 1.0

Window {
    id: window
    width: 400
    height: 400
    visible: true

    Control {
        id: button
        x: 100
        y: 100
        width: 100
        height: 40

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: button.printGlobalPos()
        }

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "transparent"
            border.color: "darkorange"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, now I´m able to read relativ the x,y coordinates to the main window. For the global coordiantes I tried to add with Window.x & Window.y but it didn´t work, could you give me an advice?

Comment: Run the example I provided and drag the window around - the global coordinates will update. Have you tried that?

Comment: This QuickControl should be generic, so I can´t use any IDs, can I?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you. Which control are you talking about?

Comment: I´m sorry for the unclear description, now I need the global Position of a QComboBox. I can get the x,y Coordinates relativ to the root element with `mapToItem(null,0,0)`. If I understand you correctly, I have to add the global x,y  Coordinates of the root Element, but how do I do that?

Comment: What is your root element? If it's not a `Window` or `ApplicationWindow`, you'll need to find the window and add its `x` and `y` position to get the global position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89131/discussion-between-refma77-and-mitch).

Answer (score 1):

For the `x` and `y` coordinates are relative to the parent for all the item but the top ones (aka `Window`), you can get them at least by walking through the parent chain to the main `Window`, for which those variables indicate the position relative to the `Screen`.

It's a matter of additions and subtractions during the journey through the parent chain, quite annoying indeed, but I don't know if there exists another solution.

Comment: For inner `Item`s there're the `mapToItem`/`mapFromItem` functions. `Screen` should provide some helper function for top level containers.

Comment: It makes sense. :-) ... It looks to me that you can use `mapToItem` to short the parent chain, but you still need to get the offset to the `Screen` once you have the relative position of the item, for `mapToItem` maps to the most top one (as an example, the `ApplicationWindow`). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

object mapFromGlobal(real x, real y)

Maps the point (x, y), which is in the global coordinate system, to the item's coordinate system, and returns a point matching the mapped coordinate.
This QML method was introduced in Qt 5.7.